# How did Jeff Atwood come up with his gravatar logo image with the black and white spiky haired guy?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, logo

I always wondered where Jeff Atwood got his logo from or if it was created from scratch where the inspiration came from.

Comment: I ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​didn't.

Comment: Whoever voted to close ... if we can have questions about Jon Skeet, Rich B and TheTXI, then I think we can have questions specifically about the Trilogy's owners, too. :)

Comment: Ah, but *can* we? Certain 'subjects' seem to be taboo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logo came from the book *Code Complete*, by Steve McConnell. Steve graciously allowed Jeff to use it for his [own personal branding](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000636.html).

Comment: interesting, now i know :)

Comment: And knowing is half the battle!

Comment: Red and blue lasers is the other half.

Comment: What I want to know is what kind of *gel* @JeffAtwood used in the avatar. Could make a fortune in salons. :-D